# Automatically get all dates from Oracle in correct time zone

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

My Oracle server is in the GMT timezone, but users of my application (which uses Oracle for data storage) could be from all over the world. At the moment if a user performs an action in the program and then looks in the audit trail of the application, they will see times in GMT and so it may confuse them.

Is there any way of getting dates to automatically come out of Oracle with the correct time offset?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

- The time is 13:00 GMT+00:00 on the Oracle server
- A user logs in and their timezone is GMT+10:00
- The user performs the following query `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL`
- The user gets the following output: `23:00`

I would also like to retrieve dates that have been saved in normal tables. E.g.

- Time is 13:00 GMT+00:00
- User logs in and their timezone is GMT+10:00
- Use does some auditable action which is saved using the following query: `INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE(ACTION, ACTION_TIME) VALUES ('Did something', SYSDATE);`
- User views audit trail and the date/time of the action is in their local time e.g. 23:00

Comment: Applying an offset to a time is a UI matter, although you can do it in the BD layer. I recommend you apply it client-side

Comment: So I should retrieve dates from Oracle in the normal way and then detect the client's timezone in javascript and just make date fields add the offset?

Comment: If you set your local time zone when you connect to the database then current_date is going to handle the conversions for you: "ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-5:0';" I'd recommend a review of the docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050 ... you've already paid Oracle to think about all of the quirks of time zones (eg. what happens when your session persists across a daylight savings time boundary), so you might as well take advantage of it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `SYSDATE`, use `CURRENT_DATE`.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks - and what about selecting dates that have been saved in a normal table?

Answer (score 0):

When you work with timestamps (in PL/SQL or as data type of column) I recommend to use data type "TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE". This datatype always shows the time according client timezone. You can use also CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or LOCALTIMESTAMP which retruns a TIMESTAMP data type with resp. without timezone information. CURRENT_DATE returns a DATE data type.

Be aware, CURRENT_DATE returs the time according client time zone, but when you save this value then the timezone information is lost.

Summary of data types:

`DATE`: "Old" datetime data type, without any timezone information.

`TIMESTAMP`: Timestamp, without any timezone information.

`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`: Timestamp, with timezone information, i.e. you get the timezone of session where value was inserted into table.

`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`: Timestamp, with time zone information. Time is **always** displayed translated to local timezone, thus timezone value (e.g. +02:00) cannot be displayed. You don't know which timezone was set in session while value was inserted into table.

Something to play:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  col_date DATE,
  col_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  col_timestamp_tz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  col_timestamp_local TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE);

ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-01:00';
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (CURRENT_DATE, LOCALTIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT t.*, SESSIONTIMEZONE, DBTIMEZONE 
FROM myTable t;

ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-05:00';
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (CURRENT_DATE, LOCALTIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT t.*, SESSIONTIMEZONE, DBTIMEZONE 
FROM myTable t;
```